# Algebra question about inequalities

Tags: inequality, summation

> Let $n>0$ and let there be two positive integers $x,y$ such that $x^n+y^n=1$ Prove, $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1+x^{2k}}{1+x^{4k}}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1+y^{2k}}{1+y^{4k}}\right)<\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-y)}$$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You mean like add more than the problem itself?

Comment: Exactly. It is good practice to include some background information with your questions and what you already tried to solve your problem. See our [FAQ on asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more information.

Comment: At least, there are no positive integers $x$, $y$ satisfying $x^n + y^n = 1$. Did you mean positive real numbers?

Comment: I think he/she did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my solution:

For each real $t \in (0,1)$,$$\frac{1+t^2}{1+t^4}=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{(1-t)(1-t^3)}{t(1+t^4)}<\frac{1}{t}$$

Subistute, $t=x^k$ and $t=y^k$ will yield,$$
0<\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1+x^{2k}}{1+x^{4k}}<\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{-k}=\frac{1-x^n}{x^n(1-x)}$$
 Also,

$$0<\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1+y^{2k}}{1+y^{4k}}<\sum_{k=1}^{n} y^{-k}=\frac{1-y^n}{y^n(1-y)}$$

Since $x^n+y^n=1$ then,

$$\frac{1-x^n}{x^n(1-x)}=\frac{y^n}{x^n(1-x)}$$

Also,

$$\frac{1-y^n}{y^n(1-y)}=\frac{x^n}{y^n(1-y)}$$

Combining the two will yield,

$$(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1+x^{2k}}{1+x^{4k}})(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1+y^{2k}}{1+y^{4k}})<(\frac{x^n}{y^n(1-y)})(\frac{y^n}{x^n(1-x)})$$

Which gives us the desired result.

Comment: Yes, sorry I will edit.